# ListView как сделать чтобы у CheckBox не убиралась галочка?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Купон" Width="100">
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox Name="CheckCupo" Margin="35, 0, 0, 0" Checked="CheckCupo_Checked" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Код:

```
private void CheckCupo_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cupon_item--;
    product.Price = product.Price - Convert.ToInt32(product.Price / 10);
    LW.Items.Refresh();
}
```

При нажатии исчезает галочка с CheckBox из за **Refresh()**. Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Один клик ставит галочку, второй снимает. Вам нужно другое проведение?

Comment: @Андрей Проблема в том, что когда я ставлю галочку и происходит Refresh таблицы (так как данные в ней меняются) галочка слетает.

Comment: Не делайте `Refresh()`, реализуйте `INPC`. Ну и изучите возможности `Binding`

Comment: @Андрей что-то как один большой костыль программа выглядит при попытке изменить на INPC всё... есть вариант как обойтись на этот раз без этого?

Comment: Добавил IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" а в код public Nullable<bool> IsChecked { get; set; } и теперь всё работает, но вместо пустого квадрата изначально стоит квадрат с черным квадратом внутри =\

Comment: Это потому что у вас Nullable<bool>, оставьте обычный bool

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Добавил

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

а в код (в продукцию).

```
public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
```

и теперь всё работает.

*(за подсказку спасибо **Андрей**)*